# Что делать в 9patch

Tags: android, button, design, photoshop

Какие элементы в андроид приложении нужно делать "тянущимися", а какие нет.

Comment: Нормальный, конкретный вопрос хватит минусить, пусть вопрос глуповат, но в топе какие-то бредовые холивары, а написать или ссылку лень? Dubok79 - спасибо, хоть кто-то ответил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, наверное те которые должны без искажения растягиваться на ширину или длину экрана. Например у вас есть некий список на кастомном адаптере. Его ширина может меняться в зависимости от разрешения экрана, так же как и высота, в зависимости от данных которые в нем есть. Ну представьте себе список приложений на Youtube или в PlayMarket. Вот фон этих пунктов есть смысл делать и делают на nine-path. Я делал всякие кнопки, которые на всю ширину экрана. Да мало ли каких вариантов может быть. Все определяется по ходу написания приложения. Главное представлять себе как это работает и применять по необходимости. Мне кажется каких то строгих канонов нету.